# How can I revoke a user's PGP key?

Tags: pgp, pgp-desktop

We have a user who has since left the company who had PGP Desktop & Email encryption.

We have just received a request to change the addresses on the account, but our corporate addresses are still on the request. How can I remove them?

I want to either "kill" the account completely, or remove our mail addresses from it.

Not got much experience of PGP, so any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The user's keys (public and private) are under key management by the PGP product suite.  Removal (or just moving to an archive store if you have legal requirements to hold his mail for audits/discovery) of the users keys should address the issue.  PGP uses the e-mail address as the user's identity.  Therefore, the keys are of no further value to the user as he will not be getting or sending e-mails from your company.

Comment: He has got 3 email addresses associated with the account, 2 corporate and a personal. He no longer has access to corporate mail - so will this prevent him from using PGP to encrypt mail? I'm just trying to ascertain if there is any way he can spoof his mail as being from our corporate environment.

Comment: I would look at the specifics of the keys in key management.  Spoofing e-mail is trivial so controlling his private key(s) would be my first choice for addressing the situration.

Comment: I don't the solution here, but it sounds like you never should have let him mix them in the first place.